# What is the correct way to ask "How do I get to your school" in Mandarin?

Tags: translation, meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, phrase-request

Here my focus is to understand the *correct usage* of 怎么走 and 到.

The English sentence is, **"How do I get to your school"**. This is in terms of asking the directions to reach the school.

I found three possibilities to ask the question in Chinese :

**1. 到你的学校怎么走**

**2. 怎么走到你的学校**

**3. 你的学校怎么走**

I know the individual meaning of these words/phrases but don't know which of the above sentence conveys the meaning in the best sense.

It would be great if someone could explain how do these words go with each other (generally) when asking for directions and even if there is a better way to put this sentence!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
1.到你的学校怎么走

3.你的学校怎么走
```

They are ok,and 3. is a very authentic way to say it.
but,

```
2.怎么走到你的学校
```

it will suddenly make Chinese know that you don't speak Chinese.
You can add one word to make this sentence authentic:

2'. 怎么走到你的学校去

Answer (score 1):

All of the three sentences work. People can know what you want to express without problem occurred.

Comment: Okay. But how would native Chinese speakers put the sentence "how do I get to your school"? I got this sentence in Duolingo and the first one was the translation, which many native speakers said was never heard.

Comment: I think this problem is summed up by a meme: [你是哪里人？](https://i.redd.it/nkdce1vbc9241.jpg).  Basically there's many ways to say "How do I get to your school?", and Duolingo chooses one as correct.  (There's [a discussion at Duolingo](https://forum.duolingo.com/comment/25231395/%E5%88%B0%E4%BD%A0%E7%9A%84%E5%AD%A6%E6%A0%A1%E6%80%8E%E4%B9%88%E8%B5%B0%EF%BC%9F).)

Comment: That meme shows amazing numbers of ways to ask where are you from. But in my current 3 translations, when I use Google to translate 你的学校怎么走 to English, I get the result as "How is your school going?". So, I don't get how will people interpret this statement. And ironically, I got confused due to the same Duolingo discussion and therefore asked this question ;)

Comment: @aymusbond I have a feeling that using google translate to translate a whole sentence is unreliable.

Comment: Completely agreed. That's why it would be great if you could tell me what would "你的学校怎么走" mean to you?

Comment: @aymusbond It depends on different circumstances, and may be "undefined behavior". Even if the same situation occurred. Not guarantee to use the same specific words to form the sentence. I will use your sentence 你的學校怎麼走 simply because I had read your sentence. If I want to be more courteous I use 請問你的學校怎麼走. If I see your sentence "how do I get to your school" and want to translate it, maybe I generate 我如何到你學校. And not guarantee that if I generate the same things when I see the same things or the same situation occur in the future.

Comment: @aymusbond Just like the comment of Becky 李蓓. It do have a lot of variation.

Answer (score 1):

It should be"你的學校要怎麼走"or"我要怎麼到你的學校"

Comment: Thanks. What sense would the 3rd translation "你的学校怎么走" make to you?

Comment: How do I get to your school

Answer (score 1):

What is the best way to get to your school?
去你学校的最佳方式是什么？

Comment: lol, this sounds unnatural...

Comment: After getting such a variety of answers, I can actually relate to the meme shared by Becky : https://i.redd.it/nkdce1vbc9241.jpg ;-)

Comment: 根据朱老师句子不‘unnatural'. Could change fangshi to 路线

Comment: I would translate `What is the best way to get to your school`to `去你學校最好的方式是什麼?` in spoken language.

Comment: （谚）达到目的的方法不止一种; There is more than one way to skin a cat.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is 去你學校該怎麽走？ (To your school, how should we go about it?)

Answer (score 1):

How should I go to your school?
我应该怎样去你的学校呢？

Answer (score 1):

The second one 怎么走到你的学校 reads as "how to walk to your school". You should avoid use this expression if you are trying to traffic with other methods (public traffic, vehicle for example).

你的学校怎么走 or 要去你的学校，我该怎么走 means "how to traffic to your school". Based on your context, it includes all transportation method.

我该怎么去你的学校 literally "how can I get to your school". It could be asking the route of traffic. But based on the context, it may also mean "what should I do so I can get permission to enter your school" (maybe a someone have to file a form for any visitors), or even "what should I do so I can study in your school".

Answer (score 1):

Also can say like

```
1.我該如何去你的學校?
2.我該怎麼去你的學校?
3.要到你學校該怎麽走?
```

It's not really same using `怎麼走到你的學校`
Because the word "走" in here is just like walk, but if in the 3rd one is means how to get there as a spoken language. So `怎麼走到你的學校` is more like `How do I walk to your school.` You can also use `去` like `go to` or `to go` . `怎麼去?`== `How to get there?`

Comment: Okay, so 走 is used only when referring to "walking'? Is there any other difference?

Comment: If only ask "How to get there" we will say "怎麼走" as a spoken language, but in middle of sentence, "走"  is mostly means "walk". Other meaning like leave "走開" ="go away",direction "走向" = "Towards" , lose the original "走樣"="Lose shape"...

Comment: And a special in classical Chinese "走" is "run". Like "不脛而走".